# Input placeholder not vertically aligned in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, placeholder

In my website, the placeholder of a text input is positioned high in the text input, only in firefox. In all other browsers it is vertically centred.

Image of firefox:

[image]

[In this jsfiddle that I made](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18899/) with exactly the same code, it is vertically centred in firefox.

What may be causing it to be at the top of the input in firefox in my website, when it is not at the top in the jsfiddle?

code:

html:

```
<div id="search-button">
            <input id="search-input" placeholder="SEARCH KEY WORD"></input>
            <div id="search-icon"></div>
       </div>
```

css:

```
#search-button,
#search-icon {
  font: 200 14px 'Helvetica Neue' , Helvetica , Arial , sans-serif;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 64px;
}
#search-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #00bfff;
}
input,
textarea,
button {
  outline: none;
}
#search-input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  color: #00bfff;
}
#search-icon {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url("../../assets/images/home_page/search-blue.svg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `line-height` and `height` equal so that text and placeholder will come centered vertically like this

**css**

```
#search-input {
    line-height:40px;
    height:40px;
}
```

> Line height will give height to value inside textbox and height we know very well if both are equal text will show vertically center

Comment: Unfortunately this messes it up on Safari. Chrome handles either cases pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce the exact effect you mention. As you say, it doesn't show up in the fiddle. I did notice that you are using `line-height` to  handle text spacing in the element. This can be effected by local browser font settings (you may have some custom browser font setting or something going on).

You may want to try setting the spacing of the text in the search box using the `padding` property instead, which will not be affected by any `font-height` effects of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I was already targeting the specific browsers to colour the placeholder, so I just added a line-height attribute to the firefox one.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: brand-blue;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: brand-blue;  
   line-height 60px;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: brand-blue;  
   line-height 60px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: brand-blue;
}
```

Not really the best practice answer, but my scenario just didn't allow a better answer to work for some reason.